# I am getting this Response code 415 in Asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have upgraded .net core project version from 2.2 to Asp.net core 3.1 earlier i was getting 200 ok response code but now i am getting 415 response code in one action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ContentValidation("Test.xsd")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "User")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Test test)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show us the settings done with AddMvc or AddControllers ?

Comment: Do you send an JSON-Request or anything else like XML? Default media type for ASP.NET Core is JSON.

Comment: @CodeNotFound this is Asp.net core Web api                                       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // in startup.cs
            services.AddControllers();
     }

Comment: @YashPatil yes I know. What I'm asking is the configuration you've inside the ConfigureServices for AddMvc or AddControllers.

Comment: @CodeNotFound yes its under ConfigureServices for AddControllers

Comment: @keuleJ we are sending xml

Comment: @YashPatil so KeuleJ answered to your question. You can to activate the XML media type. More details here => https://gavilan.blog/2020/01/22/asp-net-core-3-1-accept-and-content-type-adding-xml-support-to-a-web-api/

Comment: @CodeNotFound if i will add services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters(); in configure services it will solve my problem right ?

Comment: @YashPatil exact.

Comment: @CodeNotFound then it will only support for xml and when i want to pass both then what could be the way Thanks for Quick response

Comment: @YashPatil it will will add it in the collection of supported media types. the application/json will still be there until you explictly remove it.

Comment: @CodeNotFound you mean when i will add services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters(); it will support both formats

Comment: @YashPatil Exactly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments below your question, you're sending your data in XML format. With ASP.Net Core 3.1, the default format is JSON and you need to opt for XML format by calling `AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()` after `services.AddControllers()` like below:

```
services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Side Note: The JSON format will still be supported.